# adding external image tag reference in SQL Server Reporting Service - internet explorer not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a page that has 2000+ rows and each row has two spark-line images. It takes forever to load the report from real time data. What I did is to create those images in advance and embed the images in report(add through normal SSRS external images). Even though, it still takes about 10 min to fully load the page and the performance is not acceptable.

What I found is that the reportview webcontrol wraps the images in a very cumbersome way and made the simple process overly complicated. After some research, I customized the ReportingServices.js to add the  tag dynamically when the report page is loaded. I add HTML literal in the SSRS report using  and here is what's in the resulting page.

HackImage:http://myinternal_website/common/securitygraphs/price_1m_xs/price_1m_03076C10_xs.png

I use javascript function to replace the  tag with  and using the URL in the innerHTML of SPAN as the src of the img tag. Below is the code at the end of ReportingServices.js

```
function HackImageTag(){
 var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
 var url;
 var i = spans.length; 
 var parent;
 var myImg = document.createElement('img');
 var newImg;  
 while(i--) {
  url=spans[i].innerHTML;
  var n = url.search("HackImage:");
  if (n>=0){
   newImg=myImg.cloneNode(false);
   newImg.src=url.replace("HackImage:", "");
   parent=spans[i].parentNode;   
   parent.insertBefore(newImg, spans[i]);
   parent.removeChild( spans[ i ] );
  }
 }
}

function pageLoad(){
 HackImageTag();
}
```

I have tested that both HackImageTag() and pageLoad() run twice(once for the header page and once for the report viewer page(i believe) when the report is loaded. I am sure the code is running. However, Chrome and FireFox show the expected result. The page is loaded under 2 min. BUT, internet explorer hangs. The report never shows up.

I spent quite some time debugging the javascript. Since I am not using ASP.net, I cannot control the controls of reportviewer. It seems the SSRS page render my code(in pageload()) early in the steps and the reportviewer is never reaching a state of fully loaded.

I am not sure if there is another way I can change the images after the page is loaded. Am I on the right direction?

Comment: You probably already considered this, but if there aren't too many combinations of points along the axis you could pre-render the sparkline images and just pick the correct image to show at run-time.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. Referring the sparkline image as external image. But it is very slow. Thank you for your response but all I am asking here is to go beyond the regular SSRS report attaching image approach.